Ignite Compute job to load data from Snowflake
I want to load data into Ignite from Snowflake using Ignite Compute. I have the snowflake driver available in all the server nodes and the client nodes. When the Ignite compute job runs, it errors out with the following exception. The issue looks like its not able to serialize an lambda expression. Is there a way to disable seralization of lambda expressions? Is there another way to load data into Ignite? I have tried using data streamers but need better performance in loading data to Ignite.
Caused by: class org.apache.ignite.binary.BinaryObjectException: Lambda is not serializable: class net.snowflake.client.core.QueryContextCache$$Lambda$975/0x00000008011d6018 at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.<init>(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:325) at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryClassDescriptor.<init>(BinaryClassDescriptor.java:156) at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.createDescriptorForClass(BinaryContext.java:675) at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryContext.descriptorForClass(BinaryContext.java:633) at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal0(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:182) at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:165) at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.marshal(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:152) at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.doWriteObject(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:519) at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.doWriteObjectArray(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:769) at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryWriterExImpl.writeObjectArrayField(BinaryWriterExImpl.java:1323) at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor$DefaultFinalClassAccessor.write0(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:650) at org.apache.ignite.internal.binary.BinaryFieldAccessor.write(BinaryFieldAccessor.java:157) ... 93 more
Tried with URIDeploymentSPI but still have issues

How are you deploying the lambda to the cluster? And what does the lamdba do? Does it, for instance, use a model class (i.e., one that defines your cache structure)? And what problems did you see with the data streamer? It's pretty quick.

The lambda is from the snowflake driver. I have added the driver as a dependency and triggered the ignite compute job to run on the node.

Please share (some of) the code. It looks like you're trying to send the connection over the network or store it in a cache.
